# Laravel/Valet, how to run a project with php < 7

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-valet, caddy

So I'm working on an old project which need php5.6 to work.

Since I'm tired of Homestead I've decided to swith to Laravel/Valet however Valet is running with PHP 7.

I've read from [that discussion](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/valet-custom-driver-with-other-php-version) that a way of configure what I want is to use Caddy But when I look into `~/.valet` folder I do not see any Caddy folder but instead I see Nginx.

So has Valet change his server configuration in this case shall I create a file in Nginx to specify my configuration **OR** do I have to install Caddy myself and if so How do I tell Valet to use Caddy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [sphp](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions) to switch PHP on macOS sierra like

```sh
$ sphp 56

$ sphp 70

$ sphp 71
```

To switch valet PHP just follow 3 steps

1. `valet stop`
2. `sphp [56|70|71|72]`
3. `valet start`

If you find an NGINX error, check the logs at:

- `/usr/local/var/log/php-fpm.log`
- `/usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log`

If PHP fpm quits, you must match your PHP version used to install valet, compare the version config with other. To compare 7.0 and 5.6:

- `/usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php-fpm.d/www.conf`
- `/usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php-fpm.d/www.conf`

The important configs for valet are

1. Unix user/group of processes

   ```
   user = _www
   group = _www
   ```
2. The address on which to accept FastCGI requests.

   ```
   listen = /Users/[your_mac_user_name]/.valet/valet.sock
   ```
3. Set permissions for unix socket

   ```
   listen.owner = _www
   listen.group = _www
   listen.mode = 0777
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can install multiple versions of PHP with home brew.
To install php56 you'll need to unlink php70 first

```
brew unlink php70
```

and follow that up by installing php56

```
brew install php56
```

Now you'll have php56 on the command line, however there may be a lingering php70 fpm process. To stop it you'll need to run:

```
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php70.plist
```

and load in php56 fpm

```
launchctl load -w  /usr/local/opt/php56/homebrew.mxcl.php56.plist
```

and if you want php56 fpm to start on start up

```
cp /usr/local/opt/php56/homebrew.mxcl.php56.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/
```

To switch back to php70 just run the reverse of the above.

Comment: Thank for the answer however I would advise you to use [brew-php-switcher](https://github.com/philcook/brew-php-switcher). And anyway this is not what I asked at all ^^